# How to join 2 tables without creating duplicated rows of records in SQL

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables (Table 1 and Table 2) which I would like to join and get the records of ALL dates..

I tried left join on Table1.productid = Table2.productid but it does not give me the expected output that I want..

Does anyone have experience in solving this type of join in SQL?

[image]

Comment: Please write your code for join. you can read stackoverflow help for write good question

Comment: @Amirhossein I tried full outer join but it doesnt work. The sales value in my joined table gets duplicated instead of being 0 on rows where it should be 0..

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: @adelle use distinct in select . like my answer is below

Answer (score 2):

Use UNION ALL

```
SELECT 
    t1.Date_id,
    t1.Product_id,
    t1.Clicks,
    0 AS Sales
FROM table1 t1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    t2.Date_id,
    t2.Product_id,
    0 AS Clicks,
    t2.Sales
FROM table2 t2
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do a full outer join to get the output as follows

```
         select case when a.date_id is null then b.date_id end as date_id
                ,case when a.product_id is null then b.product_id else a.product_id end as product_id
                ,case when a.clicks is null then 0 else a.clicks end as clicks
                ,case when b.sales is null then 0 else b.sales end as sales
           from table1 a
full outer join table2 b
             on a.product_id=b.product_id
            and a.date_id=b.date_id
```

Comment: Hi @GeorgeJoseph, thanks for this, I tried but the table result returned columns with null values..

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may work:

```
INSERT INTO Your_new_table3(DateId, ProductId, Clicks, Sales)
SELECT * FROM Table1 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Table2;
```

Comment: That does not create the desired output because clicks and sales aren't separate columns in the source tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Outer Apply . [Read Microsoft doc about this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
SELECT 
    t1.Date_id,
    t1.Product_id,
    t1.Click,
    t2.Sales
FROM 
    table1 t1
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 *
        FROM table2 t2 
        WHERE t2.productid = t1.productid 
    ) t2
```

OR use `Group by` statement :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    String_agg(t1.Date_id,'-'),
    t1.Product_id,
    t1.Click,
    t2.Sales
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.productid = t1.productid 
Group by     t1.Product_id,
             t1.Click,
             t2.Sales
```

OR sue Distinct statement :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.Date_id,
    t1.Product_id,
    t1.Click,
    t2.Sales
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.productid = t1.productid
```

Comment: the date_id are not similar, how can we left join on the date_id from both tables? @Amirhossein

Comment: @adelle I apologize. that was my fault. I corrected it right.

Comment: @adelle you have a different date in Select  statement. if you delete date_id view the result is correct, and not duplicate. its advantage of join, but any time is bad result. you should use Group by  and other statment. like union or...